# Volume using disk method $y = 2\sqrt{x} \quad y=x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$y = 2\sqrt{x}$

$y=x$

about $x=-2$

I know that $y=x$ is on the outside and they meet at 4.

I need these in terms of y since I rotate about y.

$x = y$

$x = \frac{y^2}{4}$

$$\pi \int_0^4 (y - (-2))^2 - \left(\frac{y^2}{4} - (-2)\right)^2 dy$$

$$\pi \int_0^4 (y + 2)^2 - \left(\frac{y^2}{4} + 2\right)^2 dy$$

$$\pi \int_0^4 y^2 + 4y +4 - \left(\frac{y^4}{16} +4y+4\right) dy$$

$$\pi \int_0^4 y^2 - \frac{y^4}{16} dy$$

$$\pi \left(\frac{y^3}{3} - \frac{y^5}{16*5}\right)$$

Gives me $\dfrac{128\pi}{15}$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you went wrong?

Comment: Your setup looks just fine. (Nice work!) If your answer and the textbook's don't agree, then it's possible that you made an error in some step of your calculations. If you'll include those, we can take a look, and perhaps spot the error. (It's also possible that the book has a misprint, or that you're looking at an answer in the book that goes with a different problem.)

Comment: I will edit in my work, my answer was way off though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer, your expansion of the *subtracted* term is off:

$$\pi \cdot \int_0^4 (y + 2)^2 -\left (\frac{y^2}{4} + 2\right)^2 dy$$

So far, so good. Your set up looks fantastic.

But note that expanding the subtracted square, we get:

$$\pi \cdot \int_0^4 y^2 + 4y +4 - \left(\frac{y^4}{16} +4\cdot\frac{y^2}{4} +4\right) dy = \pi \cdot \int_0^4 y^2 + 4y +4 - \frac{y^4}{16} - {y^2} -4 \,dy $$

$$\pi \cdot \int_0^4 4y - \frac{y^4}{16} dy$$

NOW integrating gives us $$\pi\left(\frac {4y^2}{2} - \frac{y^5}{5\cdot 16}\right)\Big|_0^4 = \pi\left(32 - \frac{64}{5}\right) = \left(\frac{96}{5}\right)\pi $$

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be in your second expansion. $$\begin{align}\left(\frac{y^2}4-(-2)\right)^2 &= \left(\frac{y^2}4+2\right)^2\\ &= \left(\frac{y^2}4\right)^2+2\left(\frac{y^2}4\right)(2)+(2)^2\\ &= \frac{y^4}{16}+y^2+4.\end{align}$$

Can you get the rest of the way from there?

Comment: Yeah but I can't get the book answer.

Comment: Well, given that, you should be looking at $$\pi\int_0^44y-\frac{y^4}{16}\,dy,$$ yes? What did you do from there?

Comment: Basically what is in my question, I keep doing it over and getting the same.

Comment: What *precisely* did you do from there? Again, we can't tell in which step you went wrong unless you tell us your steps.

Comment: $$\pi * \int_0^4 y^2 + 4y +4 - (\frac{y^4}{16} +4y+4) dy$$

$$\pi * \int_0^4 y^2 - \frac{y^4}{16} dy$$

$$\pi * (\frac{y^3}{3} - \frac{y^5}{16*5})$$

Gives me $\frac{128\pi}{15}$

Comment: You didn't change anything at all, then. That first line should instead read $$\pi\int_0^4y^2+4y+4- \left(\frac{y^4}{16}+y^2+4\right)\,dy.$$ So, as I mentioned above, the next line would be $$\pi\int_0^44y-\frac{y^4}{16}\,dy.$$ At this point, of course, amWhy has given you the whole story